# How to convert a range to a delimited string in Java 8+

Tags: java-8, java-stream

How can you convert a range in Java (either using `java.util.stream.LongStream` or `java.util.stream.IntStream`) to a delimited string in Java?

I have tried:

```
String str = LongStream.range(16, 30)
                .boxed()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(str);
```

This prints:

```
16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
```

The same can be used with `IntStream`. Is there a more convenient conversion of a range to a delimited string?

Comment: In what sense do you mean the conversion could be convenient?

Comment: @mark42inbound Can you avoid boxing for example.

Comment: @gil.fernandes If the sight of `boxed` annoys you, you can replace `.boxed().map(String::valueOf)` by `.mapToObj(String::valueOf)`, which feels more idiomatic (to me anyways).

Comment: @Jubobs `.mapToObj(String::valueOf)` seems to be a good suggestion

Comment: Also, there's no need to explicitly map the `Long` to `String`. You can do it while collecting the elements. `.collect(Collectors.mapping(l -> String.valueOf(l), Collectors.toList()))`. Does this qualifies for a more convenient way?

Comment: we still use `guava` for *some* of these things (probably not this one), but still just an example: `String result = ContiguousSet.create(
                Range.closedOpen(16, 31),
                DiscreteDomain.integers())
                .asList()
                .toString();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seriously, just for the fun of it. Using guava:

```
String result = ContiguousSet.create(
                       Range.closedOpen(16, 31), DiscreteDomain.integers())
                             .asList()
                             .toString();
```

Or

```
 String result = String.join(",",
            IntStream.rangeClosed(16, 30).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new));
```

Or:

```
String result = String.join(",",
            () -> IntStream.rangeClosed(16, 31).mapToObj(x -> (CharSequence) String.valueOf(x)).iterator());
```

*Or* (seems like I got carried away a bit with this):

```
String result = IntStream.rangeClosed(16, 31)
            .boxed()
            .collect(
                    Collector.of(
                            () -> new Object() {
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            },
                            (obj, i) -> obj.sb.append(i).append(",")
                            ,
                            (left, right) -> {
                                left.sb.append(right.sb.toString());
                                return left;
                            },
                            x -> {
                                x.sb.setLength(x.sb.length() - 1);
                                return x.sb.toString();
                            })
            );
```

And after Holger's good points, here is even a simpler version:

```
    StringBuilder sb = IntStream.range(16, 30)
            .collect(
                    StringBuilder::new,
                    (builder, i) -> builder.append(i).append(", "),
                    StringBuilder::append);

    if (sb.length() != 0) {
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If you are going to use a manual collector, use the three-arg `collect` method instead of `Collector.of`. That way, your approach has a point, as it allows to omit the `boxed()`, making it more efficient. Then, don’t wrap the `StringBuilder` into another object; that’s unnecessary: `StringBuilder sb = IntStream.range(16, 30) .collect(StringBuilder::new, (b,i)->b.append(i).append(", "), StringBuilder::append); if(sb.length()!=0) sb.setLength(sb.length()-2); String result = sb.toString();`

Comment: @Holger this is how I had it initially in my IDE, what I did not like is that separate `setLength`... I'll edit good point about the wrapping though!

Answer (score 7):

With [`IntStream.mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
String s = IntStream.range(16, 30)
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sense of convenience implies less code, there is no need to explicitly map the `Long` to `String`. They can be simply mapped while collecting process. Here's the code to do so:

```
List<String> str = LongStream.range(16, 30)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(l -> String.valueOf(l), Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

The result is:

```
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

In response to the comment to whether `boxing` should be avoided, it has to happen anyway. The `range()` in this case returns an object of `LongStream` which has to be converted to a `stream` of `Long`.

According to @Jubobs The `mapToObject()` effectively returns `stream` of `Long` from the `LongStream` object.

Comment: Hmm, the output is a list and not a delimited string.

Comment: If you want it to be a `String` simply call the `toString()` after collecting the elements. It'll work too.